# Is there an option in Python/Matplotlib to set marklines in plots? (weekly, monthly, yearly)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have following question, and the title basically says it all:
I have plotted yearly data with matplotlib:

[Plot for yearly data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwuo8.png)

Since this data spans a course of over 5 years, it will be quite messy and confusing to read the plot.

So my question is if there is an option to achieve something along the lines of this:

[Plot with yearly markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAVC3.png)

This would of course be practical do achieve on a monthly or yearly base.
I was looking for a solution for this, but since english is not my native language it is a bit hard to put my question into words.

```
dfx=data2["Date"]
dfx = pd.to_datetime(dfx, errors='coerce')
data2['dfx']=dfx
weekly_data = data2.groupby("stuff").resample('W', 
on='dfx').sum().reset_index().sort_values(by='dfx')
weekly_data.set_index("dfx",inplace = True)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(65,17))

#set ticks every week
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(reset=True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())

#set major ticks format
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m %Y'))

weekly_data["stuff"].plot(x_compat=True,ax=ax,marker='o',markerfacecolor="red")
plt.title(ex)
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Stuff")
weekly_data["Stuff"].plot(x_compat=True, ax=ax)
```

I had to remove some of the lines of plot for confidentiality reasons.
I would be thankful for any input on this matter.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something like `matplotlib.pyplot.vlines`, which allows you to create vertical lines at certain x-values. For more information, visit the documentation, which can be found here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html

Comment: No problem! Can you please accept the answer if it works for you (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?